# Multistep alluvial diagram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggalluvial

I have a data frame in `R` with 6 categories `Pearson1`, `Spearman1`, `Kendall1`, `Pearson2`, `Spearman2`, and `Kendall2` and I have 6 variables `X1`, `X2`, `X3`, `X4`, `X5` and `X6`. In each category I have the ranking of the variables from highest to lowest, for example `X1` appear as the least significant in all categories (6 placement).
[image]

```
df <- data.frame(Variable = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6"),
                 Pearson1 = c(6, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1),
                 Spearman1 = c(6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                 Kendall1 = c(6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                 Pearson2 = c(6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                 Spearman2 = c(6, 5, 1, 2, 4, 3),
                 Kendall2 = c(6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4))
```

I want to create an alluvial diagram with the variables that goes from one step to the other. I want in the first column (step) to have the variables and then seeing the ranking it the 6 steps. My final result looks like this but only black and white with different textures for each variable if thats possible.
[image]

I have tried the following but it's not working

```
df_long <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "Variable")
    alluvial(df_long, col = "Variable", freq = "value",
             group = "Variable", border = "white",
             hide = c("Variable"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using the first example from the documentation as a code template](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/alluvial/vignettes/alluvial.html), and adding a "freq" column to the sample df, makes this chart. No reshaping required.

```
df <- data.frame(Variable = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6"),
                 Pearson1 = c(6, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1),
                 Spearman1 = c(6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                 Kendall1 = c(6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                 Pearson2 = c(6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                 Spearman2 = c(6, 5, 1, 2, 4, 3),
                 Kendall2 = c(6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4))
df$freq<-1
alluvial(df[1:7], freq=df$freq, cex = 0.7)
```

[image: a beautiful alluvial chart]

---

Reverse vertical order of furst column:

```
alluvial(df[1:7], freq=df$freq,
         cex = 0.7, 
         ordering = list(
           order(df$Variable, decreasing=TRUE),
           NULL,
           NULL,
           NULL,
           NULL,
           NULL,
           NULL
         )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. However how can I inverse it? meaning to see them from above to below from 1 to 6 instead of the opposite that its displayed in this graph.

Comment: Found the `ordering` attribute in the documentation. Added code to reverse the order